# Not passing null values to actionresult ASP.NET MVC Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

So Im working with a user interface where the user should be able to edit and delete it's data in the database. But when im trying to post the form, it doesnt save the changes. Here's some code:

Model:

```
namespace Aviato.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

    public partial class TimesheetEntry
    {
        [Key]
        [Column(Order = 0)]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        public int UserId { get; set; }

        [Key]
        [Column(Order = 1)]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string ProjectId { get; set; }

        [Key]
        [Column(Order = 2, TypeName = "date")]
        public DateTime EntryDate { get; set; }

        public decimal HoursWorked { get; set; }

        public virtual Project Project { get; set; }

        public virtual User User { get; set; }
    }
}
```

View:

(Index)

```
@model IEnumerable<Aviato.Models.TimesheetEntry>

@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h1>Tidrapportering</h1>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Skapa ny", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UserId)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Project.ProjectName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EntryDate)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.HoursWorked)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserId)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Project.ProjectName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EntryDate)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.HoursWorked)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Redigera", "Edit", new { id=item.UserId, item.ProjectId, item.EntryDate }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Ta bort", "Delete", new { id=item.UserId, item.ProjectId, item.EntryDate})
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>
<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Tillbaka", "Index", "User")
</div>
```

(Edit)

```
@model Aviato.Models.TimesheetEntry

@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h1>Redigera</h1>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.UserId)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Project)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.User)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProjectId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ProjectId, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProjectId)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EntryDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EntryDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EntryDate)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.HoursWorked, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.HoursWorked, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.HoursWorked)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Spara" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Tillbaka", "Index")
</div>
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int? id, string projectId, DateTime entryDate)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }

            var timesheetentry = _db.TimesheetEntries.Find(id, projectId, entryDate);

            if (timesheetentry == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }

            ViewBag.ProjectId = new SelectList(_db.Projects, "ProjectId", "ProjectName", timesheetentry.ProjectId);
            ViewBag.UserId = new SelectList(_db.Users, "UserId", "SocialSecurityNumber", timesheetentry.UserId);

            return View(timesheetentry);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(TimesheetEntry timesheetentry)
        {

            if (ModelState.IsValid) // So here's where the breakpoint skips. I get User and Project to be null in timesheetentry!
            {
                _db.Entry(timesheetentry).State = EntityState.Modified;
                _db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            ViewBag.ProjectId = new SelectList(_db.Projects, "ProjectId", "ProjectName", timesheetentry.ProjectId);
            ViewBag.UserId = new SelectList(_db.Users, "UserId", "SocialSecurityNumber", timesheetentry.UserId);

            return View(timesheetentry);
        }
```

Database:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TimesheetEntries] (
    [UserId]      INT            NOT NULL,
    [ProjectId]   NVARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
    [EntryDate]   DATE           NOT NULL,
    [HoursWorked] DECIMAL (8, 1) CONSTRAINT [DF_TimesheetEntries_HoursWorked] DEFAULT ((0.0)) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_TimesheetEntries] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([UserId] ASC, [ProjectId] ASC, [EntryDate] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_TimesheetEntries_Users] FOREIGN KEY ([UserId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Users] ([UserId]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_TimesheetEntries_Projects] FOREIGN KEY ([ProjectId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Projects] ([ProjectId])
);
```

Comment: Can you please reduce this to a readable question? Don't expect someone to read all of this, if you want an answer you will have to do better.

Comment: _[Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the **desired behavior**, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)_

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so I can kind of understand why its happening.  In your edit page you have these lines

```
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Project)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.User)
```

But this is not enough for it to be able to round trip all the data associated with these sub-objects.  If you view source on the HTML page, you should see what I mean.  A hidden HTML field cannot cope with a complex object.
If you really want to round-trip these objects then you will need to output all their fields as hidden fields, or create a template to do this.
Or simply have a view model that does not contain the sub objects.

Comment: How shall that view model look like, and how should I implement it to the Controller and View?

Comment: From what you show, you could add a view model for edit only, which is the same as the existing view model, but without the contained Project and User sub objects.

Comment: Yes, but what shall I return to the View then through the Controller?

I still need those values I put in the parameters right...

var timesheetEntryModel = new TimesheetEntryModel();
            var timesheetentry = _db.TimesheetEntries.Find(id, projectId, entryDate);

return View(timesheetEntryModel);

I cannot return timesheetentry anymore, so how shall I pass the values?

Comment: You should not be returning the domain model, you should be mapping to a view model that represents what you actually need on screen.

Answer (score 1):

TimesheetEntryModel Model= new TimesheetEntryModel(); 
return (Model);

are you use like this?

Comment: and don't use  _db.Entry(timesheetentry).State = EntityState.Modified; use {.First(model=>model.id)} for modify yours record and map the required column and in last savechanges.

Comment: Your correct, I get: "The entity type TimesheetEntryModel is not part of the model for the current context."

When using: "_db.Entry(timesheetentry).State = EntityState.Modified;" But I cannot delete it, because the Databse will not change the update then, what shall I do?

Comment: Could you be more specific? Do you mean: "_db.Entry(timesheetentry).State = {.First(model=>model.id)};?

Comment: and also see this tutorial very helpful to you https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ee712907.aspx  because this tutorial specially for ef